# How to check a file exists

Tags: linux, unix-shell

How do I determine that a file exists using a shell script?

I.e:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ Does File Exist? ]
then
    do this thing
fi
```

Comment: This really belongs on stackoverflow

Comment: Not necessarily, this kind of thing is important in init scripts and other sysadmin tools.  Thus, it shouldn't necessarily be migrated from either site to the other.

Comment: If you're not even able to read a man page, you really should have a look at superuser.com

Comment: Benoit:  The question is fine, I think, if you listen to podcast #58, they want questions like this.  As a demo, Joel asked how to move the turtle in LOGO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo/1003856#1003856

Comment: Kyle: As far as I understand, SF is for sys/admin related questions (even simple ones yes).
But this questions is more about learning how to use an O/S, not about managing a server.
That's why I think this question belongs to superuser.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want /bin/bash unless you need to use /bin/sh, /bin/sh is more restricted.  So if you are using bash:

Like so:

```
 if [[ -e filename ]]; then
    echo 'exists'
 fi
```

If your filename is in a variable, then use the following, the double quotes are important if the file has a space in it:

```
if [[ -e "$myFile" ]]; then
   echo 'exists'
fi
```

If you are using sh, and want to be compatible with the IEEE Std 1003.1,2004 Edition, then use single brackets instead.  The -e switch is still supported.

Comment: this is bash / ksh only, not posix.

Comment: Single brackets are an alias for test, which is a shell built-in. [[ ]] is a part of the extended bourne shell syntax of ksh and was adopted by bash.

Comment: change line 1 to #!/bin/bash, then you don't have to think about if it is ksh or bash.

Comment: @johan: Yes, and redirecting stderr of a compiler fixes all it's complaints.

Answer (score 8):

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html

Answer (score 5):

`if [ -f filename ]`

will test for the existence of a regular file.  There are other switches you can pass it to check for an executable or other attributes of a file.

Comment: that works, but '-e' is the test for existence (regardless of what it is - file, symlink, device node, named pipe etc).  '-f' tests whether it is a regular file.  in bash, run 'help test' for a full list of such tests.

Answer (score 1):

[Reference page for file testing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html)

Once you run through all those pages,
Keep this [Reference sheet](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html) handy.

Answer (score 1):

Just to note that if you want something that works across all sh shells (not only bash) and cross-platform, the only way is:

```
ls filename >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
   echo "File exists"
fi
```

Comment: Check it for folder with same name....

Comment: You can get rid of the $? nonsense.  if ls filname > /dev/null ; then echo file exists ; fi

Answer (score 0):

There is always the man pages:

`man test`